# Jquery move element from center to left and left to center

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Please help me to solve this problem. I have a code which will move the div from center to left if click moveLeft and left to center when I click moveCenter using jquery animate(); here's my code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Store offset before any animations
// (using .each here, but it could also be done in a click handler,
// before starting the animation)
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    // Retrieve the offsets later
    var element = $('.page-container');
    $('.moveLeft a').on('click', function(){
            element.data("originalOffset", element.offset());
            $('.page-container').animate({left:-element.offset().left*2},'slow');
    });

    $('.moveCenter a').on('click', function(){
            var offsetBack = element.data("originalOffset");
            $('.page-container').animate({left:offsetBack.left},'slow');
    });

});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
.page-container
{
    width:700px;
    height:1000px;
    background:#000;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="moveLeft"><a href="#">MoveLeft</a></div>
<div class="moveCenter"><a href="#">MoveCenter</a></div>
<div class="page-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code, never worked for me. I tried also to used jquery data() but doesn't work too.

Do I need to use another function instead of animation()?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please check this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9E2WQ/1/

You were very close.

The problem is that that every time you clicked `.moveLeft a` it was updating the start position every time. This would mean that the `element` would never get back to center.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but if I try to click the .moveLeft, it seems like just a toggle? Anyway, thanks a lot for taking a time to fix my code.

Comment: Ok - updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guySS/
Just added a flag to see if it had moved already. This should resolve the toggle problem.